# Pythonic way to handle arguments with values in Union

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

In the code below, `print_pos` accepts one argument which can be of
three different types.

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

pos_t = Tuple[int, int]
anchor_t = Tuple[str, str]
anchor_pos_t = Tuple[anchor_t, pos_t]

def print_pos(
        pos: Union[
            pos_t,
            anchor_pos_t,
            List[Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t]]
        ]
) -> None:
    if isinstance(pos, tuple) and isinstance(pos[0], int):
        print('xy =', pos)
    elif isinstance(pos, tuple) and isinstance(pos[0], tuple):
        print('anchor =', pos[0])
        print('xy =', pos[1])
    elif isinstance(pos, list):
        print('[')
        for p in pos:
            print_pos(p)
        print(']')
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid pos')

print_pos((0, 100))
print_pos((('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100)))
print_pos([
    (0, 100),
    (('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100))
])
```

Right now, I use `isinstance` to check for the different possibilities
for the type of `pos` but I find the code rather clumsy.  Is there a
more convenient/elegant way to do that?  In particular is there a mean
to reuse types I defined (`pos_t`, `anchor_t`, `anchor_pos_t`) in my type check?

Comment: No, this is what you ultimately have to do. This is "clumsy" because you've typed it that way. There's no getting around that (you can use a library that does it *for you* of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`typeguard`](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) library to check variable types at runtime.

This library is mainly for runtime type validation, rather than conditional type checking, so an extra `is_type` function needs to be defined to fit your needs.

Extra type casts are also unfortunately necessary to prevent type checker errors.

```py
from typing import Any, List, Tuple, Union, cast

from typeguard import check_type


pos_t = Tuple[int, int]
anchor_t = Tuple[str, str]
anchor_pos_t = Tuple[anchor_t, pos_t]


def is_type(value: Any, expected_type: Any) -> bool:
    """
    Return whether the given value is of the expected type or not.
    """
    try:
        check_type('<blank>', value, expected_type)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False


def print_pos(
    pos: Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t, List[Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t]]]
) -> None:
    if is_type(pos, pos_t):
        pos = cast(pos_t, pos)
        print('xy =', pos)
    elif is_type(pos, anchor_pos_t):
        pos = cast(anchor_pos_t, pos)
        print('anchor =', pos[0])
        print('xy =', pos[1])
    elif is_type(pos, List[Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t]]):
        pos = cast(List[Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t]], pos)
        print('[')
        for p in pos:
            print_pos(p)
        print(']')
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid pos')


print_pos((0, 100))
print_pos((('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100)))
print_pos([(0, 100), (('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100))])
```

This isn't the cleanest solution, but it works.

I would recommend using a more object-oriented approach with classes if possible, to eliminate the need for union types.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at typeguard. It's much more readable indeed. I have very few such cases so using classes only for that purpose would be too heavy in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This does not yet work with any current python version, but python 3.10 (planned to be released October 2021) will have structural pattern matching.

This allows something like this, which might be slightly more readable:

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

pos_t = Tuple[int, int]
anchor_t = Tuple[str, str]
anchor_pos_t = Tuple[anchor_t, pos_t]

def print_pos(
        pos: Union[
            pos_t,
            anchor_pos_t,
            List[Union[pos_t, anchor_pos_t]]
        ]
) -> None:
    match pos:
        # need to match this more specific case first, as tuple((x, y)) matches this as well
        case tuple(((a, b), (x, y))):
            print('anchor =', (a, b))
            print('xy =', (x, y))
        case tuple((x, y)):
            print('xy =', (x, y))
        case list(_):
            print('[')
            for p in pos:
                print_pos(p)
            print(']')
        case _:
            raise ValueError('invalid pos')

print_pos((0, 100))
print_pos((('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100)))
print_pos([
    (0, 100),
    (('right', 'bottom'), (0, 100))
])
```

This already works with the 3.10.0a7 pre-release, although the mypy support is not there yet.

Structural pattern matching is in a sense similar to sequence unpacking like

```py
(a, b), (x, y) = pos
```

but more powerful.

The three PEPs describing structural pattern matching:

- [PEP 634 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/)
- [PEP 635 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Motivation and Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/)
- [PEP 636 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Tutorial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/)